# MailChimp, Rails and trying to update a member giving ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp, mcapi

I'm missing something again ...

I'm using `mcapi2` and can subscribe a user in a controller with little problem using the following line:

```
@response = @mcMailer.lists.subscribe("XXXXXXXX", "email" => @user.email)
```

However, when I try and update the user (having now gained their first name) using:

```
@response = @mcMailer.lists.update_member("XXXXXXXX", "email" => @user.email, "merge_vars" => {"FNAME" => params[:stat][:firstname]})
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 3..5)):
app/controllers/stats_controller.rb:135:in `upload'
```

I think I've tried all formats, but simply can't seem to get it to update the first name, so any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Still having no luck.

I've looked at the mailchimp-api code and it seems to define as update_member
:

```
def update_member(id, email, merge_vars, email_type='', replace_interests=true)
_params = {:id => id, :email => email, :merge_vars => merge_vars, :email_type => email_type, :replace_interests => replace_interests}
return @master.call 'lists/update-member', _params
end
```

And my code has been every possible variation of the following (well except the right one it would assume):

```
  mergeVars = [:FNAME => params[:stat][:firstname]]
  @response = @mcMailer.lists.update_member("XXXXXXXX", "email" => @user.email, mergeVars)
```

The mail chimp-api has the following before the def:

```
@param [Array] merge_vars array of new field values to update the member with.  See merge_vars in lists/subscribe() for details.
```

But I still have no idea where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found an article [here](http://andrewtimberlake.com/technology/how-to-add-subscribers-to-a-mailchimp-list-with-ruby.html) which suggested I try the following, and it seems to have worked. I'm still none the wiser to be honest but putting it here in case it helps anyone else.

```
@response = @mcMailer.lists.update_member("XXXXXXXX", {email: @user.email}, {'FNAME' => params[:stat][:firstname], 'LNAME' => ""} )
```

Maybe it's the inclusion of the LNAME field? Braces? Who knows!

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```
@response = @mcMailer.lists.update_member( "XXXXXXXX", @user.email, {"FNAME" => params[:stat][:firstname]})
```

The second and last parameters should not be a key/value pairs, but only values.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. Same error about the wrong number of arguments. Really frustrating! Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Sadly, if I do your suggestion, I get the message change to `Mailchimp::ValidationError (Validation error: {"email":"Please enter a struct\/associative array"}):`, so I've update the question with some more information. If there is anything else you can suggest, I'd be grateful.